# Google Maps MySQL Map with HTML InfoWindow

Tags: java, mysql, google-maps

I have scriptet me a maps with markers based on a MySQL Table.
The position is in the Table.
Now, i would like to write with HTML in the InfoWindow, because it not show HTML on the InfoWindow on the Map.

```
downloadUrl('inc/map_bridge.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var ide = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var desc = markerElem.getAttribute('beschreibung');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('art');
          var link = '<p>Klicke für weitere infos: <a href="http://link.de">Hier</a>';
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));


          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = 'ID' + ide + ': ' + name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = desc + link
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });


          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

It show only so:
show example picture

[image: [1]]

the following i have in the MySQL-Table

```
first line<br>second line
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'beschreibung' were the result of SELECT SQL, the reason is escaped SELECT 
 SQL result.

(I'm in short of reputation, so write in answer form.)